# Bash: Output columns from array consisting of two columns

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, sed

**Problem**

I am writing a bash script and I have an array, where each value consists of two columns. It looks like this:

```
for i in "${res[@]}"; do
  echo "$i"
done

#Stream1
0 a1
1 b1
2 c1
4 d1
6 e1
#Stream2
0 a2
1 b2
3 c2
4 d2
9 f2
...
```

I would like to combine the output from this array into a larger table, and multiplex the indices. Furthermore, I would like to format the top row by inserting comment `#Sec`.
I would like the result to be something like this:

```
#Sec  Stream1 Stream2
0     a1      a2
1     b1      b2
2     c1
3             c2
4     d1      d2
6     e1
9             f2
```

The insertion of `#Sec` and removal of the `#` behind the `Stream`keyword is not necessary but desired if not too difficult.

**Tried Solutions**

I have tried piping to `column` and `awk`, but have not been able to produce the desired results.

---

**EDIT**

`res`is an array in a bash script. It is quite large, so I will only provide a short selection. Running `echo "$( typeset -p res)"`produces following output:

```
declare -a res='([1]="#Stream1
0 3072
1 6144
2 5120
3 1024
5 6144
..." [2]="#Stream2
0 3072
1 5120
2 4096
3 3072
53 3072
55 1024
57 2048")'
```

As for the 'result', my initial intention was to assign the resulting table to a variable and use it in another `awk` script to calculate the moving averages for specified indices, and plot the results. This will be done for ~20 different files. However I am open to other solutions.

The number of streams may vary from 10 to 50. Each stream having from 100 to 300 rows.

Comment: what do you mean by 'result'? are you just looking to print to stdout? or are you looking to populate a new `bash` array where each entry in the array is one of your lines of output? also, could you update the question with the output from `typeset -p res` (this will allow us to verify the structure of the array as well as easily recreate the array in our environments)

Comment: how many streams can there be? while your examples show just 2x streams, the last line of your 'input' is `...` which seems to indicate (to me) that there may be more than 2x streams

Comment: Good question! Realizing, formatting will be off I will edit my post based on your questions.

Comment: I´ve edited the post! Hope it clarifies the question somewhat.

Comment: thanks for the updates; the abbreviated `typeset -p` output is fine as it gives us a better idea of the structure we're working with; unfortunately, more questions ... you mention plotting results for `~20 files`, and you mention dealing with a variable number/size of streams ... what is the relationship of these 'files' and 'streams? is a given file parsed to generate a set of streams? are you looking to plot across 1 file or all files? the current question comes across (to me) as an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) so I'm curious as to the 'bigger picture' ...

Comment: The context is that of network analysis and parsing trace files. I have run ~20 simulations, and am parsing and concatenating from various files in order to produce tables which can easily be plotted with gnuplot. My intention is to construct a table for each of these runs. This allows me to be flexible with them I gnuplot. I can also do this task by writing several scripts, and pass or pipe results to each script. However, since there are many files this seems very laborious.

Comment: anubhava's answer appears to work for a variable number/size of streams so at a minimum you could pipe your `for/echo` loop into his `awk` solution; generally speaking ... `awk` excels at parsing (multiple) input files and generating pretty much any output you can imagine ... so I'm thinking it may be possible to have just one (`awk`) script replace the 'several scripts' you mention ...

Comment: I've recently started using awk rather than python scripts for parsing, and I realize it is very powerful. Looking forward to learning more about it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```sh
cat tabulate.awk

NF == 1 {
   h = h OFS substr($1, 2)
   ++numSec
   next
}
{
   keys[$1]
   map[$1,numSec] = $2
}
END {
   print h
   for (k in keys) {
      printf "%s", k
      for (i=1; i<=numSec; ++i)
         printf "\t%s", map[k,i]
      print ""
   }
}
```

Then use it as:

```sh
awk -v OFS='\t' -v h='#Sec' -f tabulate.awk file

#Sec  Stream1  Stream2
0     a1       a2
1     b1       b2
2     c1
3              c2
4     d1       d2
6     e1
9              f2
```

Comment: Thanks for the clever solution! It works like a charm! I have another question, however. Where would I need to apply the change in order to substitute empty field values with zeros?

Comment: Use `awk -v OFS='\t' -v h='#Sec' 'NF==1{h = h OFS substr($1,2); ++numSec; next} {keys[$1]; map[$1,numSec] = $2} END {print h; for (k in keys) {printf "%s", k; for (i=1; i<=numSec; ++i) printf "\t%s", ((k,i) in map ? map[k,i] : "0"); print ""}}' file`

Comment: Man, thats a pretty elegant way to do it. Thanks for the help